Asyncio Task was destroyed but it was pending
I am making requests to an external API, getting the response back and writing it to a file. Everything works/runs fine, however I receive the "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" warning that I'd like to clean up.
I have emulated the process below. I receive items from a source (e.g. a list) of items and as I receive them, I put them into the queue, signaling the end of the list but putting in a sentinel None value.
The write_q continues to receive items from this queue until it receives the sentinel and then breaks out.
Below is the code which will show that my write_task() is cancelled before it is completed. What is the proper design to handle this?
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aiocsv
import json

async def task(l: list,  write_q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:

    # Read tasks from source of data
    for i in l:
        # Put a request task into the queue
        req: dict = {
            "headers": {"Accept": "application/json"},
            "url": "https://httpbin.org/post",
            "data": i
        }
        await write_q.put(req)

    # Sentinel value to signal we are done receiving from source
    await write_q.put(None)

async def write_task(write_q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:

    headers: bool = True
    while True:
        async with aiofiles.open("file.csv", mode="a+", newline='') as f:
            w = aiocsv.AsyncWriter(f)
            # Get data out of the queue to write it
            data = await write_q.get()
            if not data:
                write_q.task_done()
                await f.flush()
                break

            if headers:
                await w.writerow([
                    "status",
                    "data",
                ])
                headers = False

            # Write the data from the response
            await w.writerow([
                "200",
                json.dumps(data)
            ])
            write_q.task_done()

async def main() -> None:

    # Create fake data to POST
    items: list[str] = [["hello", "world"], ["asyncio", "test"]] * 5 

    # Queues for orchestrating 
    write_q = asyncio.Queue()
    producer = asyncio.create_task(
        task(items, write_q)
    )
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(
        write_task(write_q)
    )

    errors = await asyncio.gather(producer, return_exceptions=True)
    print(f"INFO: Producer has completed! exceptions: {errors}")

    # Wait for queue to empty and cancel the consumer
    await write_q.join()
    consumer.cancel()
    print("INFO: write consumer has completed! ")
    print("INFO: Complete!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())


you assigned write_task to consumer = - so maybe you should run await consumer to wait for end of this function.

You should run
await consumer

instead of
consumer.cancel()

to wait for the end of task.

import asyncio
import aiofiles
import aiocsv
import json

async def task(l: list,  write_q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:

    # Read tasks from source of data
    for i in l:
        # Put a request task into the queue
        req: dict = {
            "headers": {"Accept": "application/json"},
            "url": "https://httpbin.org/post",
            "data": i
        }
        await write_q.put(req)

    # Sentinel value to signal we are done receiving from source
    await write_q.put(None)

async def write_task(write_q: asyncio.Queue) -> None:

    headers: bool = True
    while True:
        async with aiofiles.open("file.csv", mode="a+", newline='') as f:
            w = aiocsv.AsyncWriter(f)
            # Get data out of the queue to write it
            data = await write_q.get()
            if not data:
                write_q.task_done()
                await f.flush()
                break

            if headers:
                await w.writerow([
                    "status",
                    "data",
                ])
                headers = False

            # Write the data from the response
            await w.writerow([
                "200",
                json.dumps(data)
            ])
            write_q.task_done()

async def main() -> None:

    # Create fake data to POST
    items: list[str] = [["hello", "world"], ["asyncio", "test"]] * 5 

    # Queues for orchestrating 
    write_q = asyncio.Queue()
    producer = asyncio.create_task(
        task(items, write_q)
    )
    consumer = asyncio.create_task(
        write_task(write_q)
    )

    errors = await asyncio.gather(producer, return_exceptions=True)
    print(f"INFO: Producer has completed! exceptions: {errors}")

    # Wait for queue to empty and cancel the consumer
    await write_q.join()
    await consumer
    #consumer.cancel()    
    print("INFO: write consumer has completed! ")
    print("INFO: Complete!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

